# Как в дискорде получить список всех участников по ролям?

Tags: python, discord, discord.py, discord-api

Как получить мне список участников discord-сервера с определенной ролью?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
gui = bot.get_guild(id_guild) # получаем гильдию

membrs = get(gui.roles, name="NameRole").members # получаем список участников с ролью
```